# Googlemap v3 measure - convert meters to feet and acres

Tags: google-maps, measurement

I have a googlemap with a kml layer embedded and the code I found on google developers forum is below. It is showing meters for distance and sq meters for area. How can I change this to show feet for distance and acres for area? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

4046.86 sq meters in 1 acre
3.28084 feet in 1 meter

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

                    var polyline;
                    var polygon;
                    var map;


                    function initialize() {
                      var Trigger = new google.maps.LatLng(31.3664951, -98.5192484);
                      var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 14,
                        center: Trigger,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                      };

                      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
                      var lineOptions = {
                        strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 3
                      }

                        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                            url: 'http://www.website.com/KML/filename.kmz',
                            suppressInfoWindows: false,
                            map: map
                          });
                        map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});

                      polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(lineOptions);
                      polyline.setMap(map);
                      var gonOptions = {
                        fillColor: '#0000FF',
                        fillOpacity: 0.4,
                        strokeWeight: 0
                      };
                      polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(gonOptions);
                      polygon.setMap(map);
                      // Add a listener for the click event
                      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
                    }

                    /**
                     * Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
                     * Updates the encoding text area with the path's encoded values.
                     */
                    function addLatLng(event) {
                      var lpath = polyline.getPath();
                      // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
                      // and it will automatically appear
                      lpath.push(event.latLng);
                      var gpath = polygon.getPath();
                      gpath.push(event.latLng);

                      // Update the text field
                      document.getElementById('lineLength').value = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(lpath.getArray());
                      if (gpath.getLength()>2){
                        var garray = [];
                        gpath.forEach(function(ll,num){
                          garray.push(ll);
                        });
                        // close loop.
                        garray.push(gpath.getAt(0));
                        // bug? Always return 0.
                        var a = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(garray);

                        document.getElementById('polyArea').value = a;
                      }
                    }


    </script>
```

Comment: You already have the formula.  Just use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where to put it in the javascript.

Comment: Is there anyone that can give me some help on where to add the code to convert the measurement from meters to ft for the distance and sq meters to acres for the area.

Answer (score 1):

Use the conversion factors you have:

- **4046.86 sq meters in 1 acre:** number in sq meters * 1 acre / 4046.86 sq meters = number in acres
- **3.28084 feet in 1 meter:** number in meters * 3.28084 feet / meter = number in feet

  ```
                // Update the text field
                document.getElementById('lineLength').value = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(lpath.getArray()) *  3.28084; // 3.28084 feet in 1 meter
                if (gpath.getLength()>2){
                  var garray = [];
                  gpath.forEach(function(ll,num){
                    garray.push(ll);
                  });
                  // close loop.
                  garray.push(gpath.getAt(0));
                  // bug? Always return 0.
                  var a = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(garray);

                  document.getElementById('polyArea').value = a / 4046.86; // 4046.86 sq meters in 1 acre
  ```